# Electron - Catch when window is closed using the "x" button

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

**The setup**

Looking at the [BrowserWindow Events Docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#instance-events), the `close` event is...

> Emitted when the window is going to be closed

and the `closed` event is...

> Emitted when the window is closed.

**The problem**

*Both* events are triggered when I close the window manually (i.e. clicking the "x" in the menu bar), as well as when I programmatically close the window (i.e. `window.close()`);

This window requires different handling, depending on whether I am closing the window programmatically, or manually closing it (quit the app entirely if using the "x", or do some stuffs otherwise).

**So, how do I...**

How can I differentiate between the two?

Answer (score 4):

As the documentation states, you cannot make difference between [`window.close()`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#winclose) and clicking on `X`

> `win.close()` Try to close the window. This has the same effect as a
>   user manually clicking the close button of the window.

However, you can use [`window.destroy()`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#windestroy), which generates slightly different events

> `win.destroy()` Force closing the window, the unload and beforeunload
>   event won't be emitted for the web page, and close event will also not
>   be emitted for this window, but it guarantees the closed event will be
>   emitted.

A simple example to exploit this difference would be something like the following:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

app.once('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow()
  let isRegularClose = false
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (win) win.destroy()
  }, 5000)
  win.on('close', (event) => {
    isRegularClose = true
  })
  win.on('closed', (event) => {
    console.log(isRegularClose
      ? 'win closed (X)'
      : 'win destroyed (code)')
    win = null
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**okay so:**

1. `win.destroy()` is equal to the X system native application close button according to the docs and it will always make sure the `closed` event is fired and `close` event is NOT
2. when clicking the X system native application close button you will have the `close` event fired first then the `closed` event comes after.
3. `close` event comes before the `beforeunload` and `unload` DOM events

**TIPS:**

4. as per dosc use the `closed` event to get rid of the `BrowserWindow` instance (your main window or any window created using `new BrowserWindow()`). this is etter than garbage collection. [see this here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-closed)

5. I used the `closed` event to shutdown a local database server before quiting the app. So you can use it to accomplish similar step, like this:

```js
mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
  shutdownDatabase();
  mainWindow = null; 
});
```

Comment: `and it will always make sure the closed event is fired and close event is NOT` if this were true, it isn't any longer. Both events get called when clicking "X" in macOS

Answer (score -1):

IPC is the solution for you answer.

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu, ipcMain} = electron;

let mainApp;

app.on('ready', () => {
  mainApp = new BrowserWindow({ frame: false });
  mainApp.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'public/mainApp2.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }));
  mainApp.on('closed', () => {
    app.quit();
  });
});

ipcMain.on('command:close', (event, arg) => {
  app.quit();
});
```

And on click

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
let $ = require("jquery");



// Click Events
$("#action-close").click(() => {
    ipcRenderer.send("command:close");
});
```

Comment: What is `#action-close`? Is that listening for the "x" in the menubar? Or is that a btn in the dom?

Comment: #action-close is id of an element in dom , in your case it will the div or span of 'x'

Comment: You misunderstand my question. The "x" refers to the close button of the window. In Windows OS, it's a red square in the top-right corner of the window, in the menu bar. In Mac OS, it's a red circle in the top-left corner of the window, in the menu bar. These are native to the OS window, and completely unrelated to the DOM

Comment: Oh then you can capture ''window-all-closed" event from electron as 

`app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  app.quit();
});`